# Fundamental group of a wedge sum with Van Kampen theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am working on algebraic topology.

I want to prove that for any $\Omega$, $\Lambda$ arbitrary path-connected topological spaces, $\pi_1(\Omega \vee \Lambda) = \pi_1(\Omega) \ast \pi_1(\Lambda)$, using Seifert - Van Kampen theorem and deform retract properties.

I do not understand how to construct a proper "open neighborhood" of $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$ (needed in the said theorem) that would be adapted for a deform retract.

I read Hatcher's proof in *Algebraic Topology*, yet I did not understand it.

How can I proceed ? Could you please provide me with a sketch of the proof ?

Thank you very much,
Respectfully,

A.F

Comment: But what is $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$? Arbitrary spaces?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$ are arbitrary topological spaces, path-connected

Comment: I think you should require that $\Omega,\Lambda$ are also (weakly) locally path connected

Comment: Then Lemma 1.15 of Hatcher will do the trick

Comment: Indeed to apply SvK we need to partition the space by open sets anyway

Comment: @FShrike Thank you, I read Hatcher's 1.15 lemma, yet I don't understand how it may help

Comment: If that lemma applied then any loop about the central wedge point would be a sequence of products of loops in either space, and these products would not commute. That just describes the free product of the two groups